# Does Mending work on Androids?

Tags: starfinder

Androids, being both humanoid and construct, have the following racial trait:

> ## Constructed
>
> For effects targeting creatures by type
>   androids count as both humanoids and
>   constructs (whichever effect is worse).

Given that *mending* works on "constructs", does it also affect Androids?

> ## Mending
>
> This spell repairs damaged objects and constructs, restoring
>   1d4 Hit Points.
>   [...]
>   A construct can benefit from this spell only once per day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## NO by RAW, YES by RAI

#### A Recent Update to the FAQ clarifies the Constructed Property, but Mending is unchanged.

Since many of the answers here were posted, the Starfinder core rulebook received an [errata/FAQ update](http://paizo.com/starfinder/faq) that updated the constructed property for androids. The constructed property now reads as follows:

> "For effects targeting creatures by type, androids count as both constructs and humanoids (whichever type allows an ability to affect them for abilities that affect only one type, and whichever is worse for abilities that affect both types)."

In essence, if an effect can target constructs but not humanoids, it can target them. If it can target both constructs and humanoids, but has differing effects between the two, the worse of the two effects is the result.

The problem here is now just the Mending spell. This spell is contradictory, as its target line specifies objects, while its text specifies both objects and constructs. **Its intention is clearly that constructs should be able to benefit, but the current target restriction means that technically they cannot.**

> **Targets** one object of up to 1 bulk
>
> (...)
>
> This spell repairs damaged objects and constructs, restoring 1d4 Hit Points. If the object has the broken condition, this condition is removed if the object is restored to at least half its original Hit Points. All of the pieces of an object must be present for this spell to function. A construct can benefit from this spell only once per day. Magic items can be repaired by this spell, but magic items that are destroyed don’t have their magic abilities restored. This spell doesn’t reverse effects that warp or otherwise transmute items, but it can still repair damage dealt to such items.

This spell may recieve errata in the future.

Answer (score 4):

RAW, I don't believe Mending will work on an Android. Mending is affecting creatures by type (it explicitly targets constructs). Since being a Construct would allow this beneficial spell to heal, then it is demonstrably worse to be counted as a Humanoid.

Comment: Do the normal heal spells work on constructs? If they don't, then androids are unhealable via spells (because they count as whichever is worse).

Comment: I did think about that, but the cure spells don't actually put any intrinsic restriction on what they can be cast on. Instead, they rely on the creature type to say constructs and undead can't be healed.

Answer (score 3):

**YES (Probably)....**

Constructed states:

> For **effects targeting** creatures by type androids count as both humanoids and **constructs** (whichever effect is worse).

Mending states:

> This spell repairs damaged objects and **constructs**.

Not being targeted is not a "Worse Effect" isn't a 'non-effect'

To support this statement here's a quote of Owen K.C. Stephens from the Starfinder development team on [this post.](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ljt9&page=2?Meet-the-Iconics-Iseph)

> ...If you cast raise dead on a typical computer that got broken, even one with an artificial personality, nothing happens. It has no soul.
>
> Cast it on an android, and the android is restored to life.

Per Raise Dead:

> Constructs, elementals, and outsiders can't be raised by this spell

IE: non-effects are not considered "Worse"

[Additional Related link](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uik5?Android)

**BUT ...**

Mending currently only targets: "one object of up to 1 bulk", so RAW might be that they cannot, but can be effect by Rapid Repair/Raise Dead/Mystic Cure, as an Android does meet all targeting requirements.

That being said I'd say RAI that Mending can target Androids, but we wont know 100% until an FAQ or Errata is out for the Androids, Constructed- (whichever effect is worse) statement, and possibility an Errata for Mending's "Targets" section

Comment: Construct is a creature type. Therefore, it is targeting only specific types...

Comment: @YogoZuno, Yes, and isn't an Android a construct? My reasoning here is the "Whichever effect is worse" clause, RAW that means you get the worst 'effect' if something targets both humanoids and constructs, not prevent something that targets only constructs, b/c an Android is a construct. Also RAI I don't believe preventing the targeting of buffs/heal spells and then allowing de-buffs/damage with "Whichever effect is worse" makes since.  For this question to have a correct answer, we'll need an Errata that explains "Whichever is worse" or specifics on if a Android can be targeted by Mending

Comment: Grabanksi I can't see how you need an official definition for this case. If you tried to cast Mending on a human, it would do nothing. If you tried to cast Mending on an injured Android, it could either do nothing or heal them...how could you possibly consider 'do nothing'  to not be worse than heal? Also, an Android is NOT a construct. They simply count as a construct in some limited ways and circumstances.

Comment: I'm saying not being targeted is not an Effect, so the statement (whichever effect is worse) doesn't apply. At least in my interpretation, which is why i stated that an official errata or FAQ is required.

Comment: grabanksi Rapid Repair and Make Whole are actually worse examples, since they specifically target 'one construct' - they categorically won't work on an Android. I agree, Raise Dead is a little less clear. Without the post from the developer, I would have said it didn't work either. Mind you, showing designer's intent  doesn't mean that the RAW of the spell actually works the way he claims.

Comment: There's now RAW interpretation of (Whichever effect is worse). So all's we can go off here is RAI. as such RAI clearly allows (per Developer comment) that not being targeted is NOT a 'worse effect' as the 'worse effect' for Raise dead would be that it didn't work, and it does. Therefore anything that targets Constructs and not humanoids can target Androids, as they are counted as constructs for targeting. (I think with my edits I may need to revise my post to be clearer on my points)

Comment: Comments isn't really the place for a debate, but...no, the Developer comment shows intent for Raise Dead only, based on the context. It doesn't give any sort of general intent, unless it involves a soul, since that was what was being discussed as the key difference with an android. As for 'Whichever is worse'...if there's no explicit definition, you rely on natural language meaning, which to me is pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

### Mending does not target creatures

*Mending* stat block explicitly says it targets only objects:

> **Targets** one object of up to 1 bulk

Compare this to the *Make Whole* spell:

> **Targets** one object of up to 1 bulk/level or one construct of
>   any size

**However, the spell description says it repairs constructs, doesn't it?**

The spell description mentions constructs twice:

> - This spell repairs damaged objects and constructs, restoring
>     1d4 Hit Points.
> - A construct can benefit from
>     this spell only once per day.

Can a construct creature be "one object of up to 1 bulk"? Yes it can.
To fit the "one object of up to 1 bulk" requirements it must be:

1. a single entity
2. small enough — tiny (1-8 lbs.) or smaller
3. dead enough (=inactive) to be considered an object

For instance, it can be a damaged Mechanic's tiny *Hover Drone* (Core Rulebook, page 74):

> A drone is considered a construct with the
>   technological subtype for the purposes of spells and effects
>   targeting it.
>
> Like most constructs, a drone cannot recover from damage on
>   its own. If a drone is reduced to 0 Hit Points, it becomes inactive
>   until it is restored to 1 Hit Point or more.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

> For effects targeting creatures by type androids count as both humanoids and constructs **(whichever effect is worse)**.

It does not the rule element you put in has a caveat that prevents it (emphasis mine).

If an android gets a mending, the worse outcome is that it is a humanoid and get nothing. Because if you count as a construct, you get healed.

Comment: Is this answer different than @YogoZuno's

Comment: But it is not "humanoids or constructs (whichever is worse)", is is "humanoids **and** constructs (whichever *effect* is worse)". Mending has only one effect, it targets constructs, and Androids count as humanoids **and** constructs.